# How to make a glowing shadow effect on my character with unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game about mythology with my team in Unity. It'll be a lot of work for the artist of my game to manually do the effects, so I need a dark glowing effect on the demon of the game.

Demon:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9aMESNHAn_4Y3ppemxkeks3UEE/view

It needs to be something like this:

https://youtu.be/XVLuwjATjxA?t=1m48s

The black glowing shadow effect on Lancelot Berserker, the fighter in black armor. I've attempted with the particle system, but it must be out of my current knowledge so I'd like some guidance on how to do it please.

Comment: At first glance, I would think about animated sprites with an alpha channel. I think the ParticleSystem won't give good results.

Comment: @Poohe, look at your question. Click "Edit" Look at the edit control bar.  Look at the "image" button.  Click it. That's how you add images to questions. You must do that.  Don't have links to images.

Answer (score 1):

In the particle system, go to Shape and then make the shape of type Mesh. You can then pass the mesh to the slot.

Else look for Mesh Particle Emitters component. It is legacy so maybe not the best.

Comment: My character is a 2D sprite, so any advice on that?

Comment: You should have a texture atlas with the animation of your player. Just create a second set of halo animation that overlap your player. Or even a set of player animation containing the halo and one without. The mesh emitter also works on 2d since it works on mesh. So if you need a more realistic (but more expensive) solution, try the answer I provided.

Comment: Just to extend on the mesh emitter for 2d, it uses the mesh, so the vertices. If you give a quad there is only 6 of them in each corner so you need to create a more detailed mesh. This is why I would recommend the Sprite animation solution.